# Is it possible to prevent a single container from scaling on mobile?

Tags: css, mobile

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

Let the whole page scale down except for navigation container. I am overriding some of its CSS rules to make it more accessible on smartphones, but the problem is that it uses quite a few images and I need to display those in their original size (1 image px = 1 device screen px).

Is there any technique to achieve this?

Comment: If you're going to go to the effort of controlling this, wouldn't you want all the images displayed with a ratio where you're not wasting bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the context so it's harder, but maybe you can achieve it with JavaScript and CSS, this way:

#### 1) Detect the device-width, and compare it to the document width

To retrieve the document width, you can use this snippet i found somewhere:

```
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var width = w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
```

Then get the ratio by dividing it to `screen.width`:

```
var ratio = width / screen.width;
```

---

So, let's say the device-width is 320px (iPhone potrait) and the page with is 980px (usual iPhone render).

980 / 320 = 3.0625.

---

#### 2) Zoom / scale your content to that ratio

You can do it with [CSS transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

```
-ms-transform: scale(3.0625);
-webkit-transform: scale(3.0625);
-o-transform: scale(3.0625);
-moz-transform: scale(3.0625);
transform: scale(3.0625);
```

or with [CSS zoom](http://www.fix-css.com/2011/05/css-zoom/) for modern browsers and IE:

```
zoom:3.0625;
```

or with [jQuery UI Effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/), or with [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), or with [HTML5 canvas scale](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_scale.asp) (if your target is a canvas), or with pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("idOfTheContent").style.width = document.getElementById("idOfTheContent").style.width * 3.0625;
document.getElementById("idOfTheContent").style.height = document.getElementById("idOfTheContent").style.height * 3.0625;
```

or with....any scaling/zooming method you can find around.

In any case i'm not sure about the precision of the scale (how many digits after the comma are actually processed, but i think even rounding it to an integer will be ok) and how it will render.

Let me know if it works out :-)

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer and it looks like I've got quite a few options. I'm sure something will work out. Thanks! :)